# onclick of button need to update the state value from -12 to 50

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

onclick of button need to update the state value from -12 to 50

any suggestion?

please refer below snippet

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const Test = () => {
  let commomRowData = {
    2020: { firstLevel: { children: { secondLevel: { value: -12 } } } },
  };

  const [data, setData] = useState(commomRowData);
  const updateData = () => {};
  return (
    <div>
      <div>Testing</div>
      <div>
        <button onClick={updateData}> Click </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Test;
```

Comment: How do you want to change it? From an input, random number, data from a server?  Why do you need such complex structure for a single value? Give more information about your idea.

Comment: from the server we are getting this complex structure,need to update the value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would initialize `useState`'s `data` with `-12` and update only that value on click of the button with `setData(50)`. This feels more straightforward than overwriting all of the object keys.

```
const Test = () => {  
  const [data, setData] = useState(-12);

  let commomRowData = {
    2020: { firstLevel: { children: { secondLevel: { value: data } } } }
  };

  const updateData = () => { setData(50)};
  return (
    <div>
      <div>Testing</div>
      <div>
        <button onClick={updateData}> Click </button>
        <pre>{JSON.stringify(commomRowData, null, 4)}</pre>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

[image]

[codeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/exciting-sea-dqbgg?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: let srcommomRowData = {
    2020: { firstLevel: { children: { secondLevel: { value: -12 } } } },
  };

let destommomRowData = {
    2020: { firstLevel: { children: { secondLevel: { value: 22 } } } },
  };

on click of button need to add both the value, is it possible to achieve

Comment: @Chidananda This was done purposely. The point is that the `value` of `-12` is immediately initialized with the `useState` value.

Comment: @Chidananda Please view the codeSandbox link at the bottom of my answer to see the working code.